# Failed to create scheduler job, Schedule or time zone is invalid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run a function every day at 00.00 - However, when deploying the function I'm getting this error from Firebase:

**Failed to create scheduler job projects/myProject/locations/europe-west1/jobs/firebase-schedule-checkCourseForNewClientProgram-us-central1: HTTP Error: 400, Schedule or time zone is invalid.**

I've tried setting the **timeZone()** to **"Europe/Copenhagen"**, that didn't work. I've tried setting the **region()** to **"europe-west1"**, which didn't work either. I've also tried with other formats in the "**schedule()**" function, but every time I'm getting the error when deploying :(

```
export const checkCourseForNewClientProgram = functions.pubsub.schedule("every day 00:00").onRun(async (context) => {
  ......
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the schedule and not the time zone.

Every day at midnight:

`functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')`